# React - static images sometimes importing image path, sometimes as base64

Tags: reactjs, image, import, path, base64

I am trying to import image paths and store them into the redux store.

I noticed that when importing images, it seems to randomly import either the path to that image, or the base64 data.

[image: code example screenshot]

can someone explain whats causing this behaviour, and how to make it only import the image path ( like img_1 and img_2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the file size, if file size greater than 8192 bytes, then it will be imported as path, otherwise webpack will encode it.

References:

- https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/#limit
- https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader

Answer (score 1):

Is it always images 3 and 4 that are base64? If so, it is likely they are base64 encoded files, but named task-manager-3.png and task-manager-4.png. Least that would be my first thought. Hard to say with the info at hand.

If using linux try `file task-manager-3.png` and compare it's output to `file task-manager-1.png`. If the first reports something like:

```sh
myfile.png: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

The it is more likely an image that has been base64 encoded and save with a PNG extension. A PNG file should return something like:

```sh
filename.png: PNG image data, 1731 x 458, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

To decode the base64 encoded file back to an actual PNG, you could use an online decoder such as https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also cool idea to compare the files that way. it seems like the files are the same since the output is : PNG image data, 703 x 380, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced,  and PNG image data, 388 x 302, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced. I will try to use the decoding tool and see how it behaves after